# How to setup CI for helm chart with multiple services

Tags: continuous-integration, kubernetes-helm, pipeline, cicd

### Context

I'm developing an application with the following services

- Frontend
- IAM
- Backend
- Database

Each service has it own repository contains the source code and the Dockerfile to build the image.

Currently I've created one helm chart that includes all those services. The values.yaml file looks like this;

```
frontend:
  image:
    repository:  "myimage"
    tag: "1.0.0"

iam:
  image:
    repository:  "myimage"
    tag: "1.0.3"

backend:
  image:
    repository:  "myimage"
    tag: "1.0.1"

database:
  image:
    repository:  "myimage"
    tag: "2.0.0"
```

### Question

I'm now looking into the options I have to create a CI process for all of this...

I feel like im lost in the possibilities. Every guide i read on the internet has an example for a helm chart containing only 1 service. But my chart has several and they depend on each-other.  Based on the guides I feel like I need to create one umbrella chart with subcharts for every service. So every service should get it's own chart.

**My question now is; how do you setup a proper CI (and CD) for all of this?**

Below is the flow that I've came up with (probably not correct). I'd like to automate as much as possible.

```
// frontend repo | feature branch
* Trigger: open pull request (and commit to that pr) 
- Lint
- Unit tests
- Code quality checks
- Build new image (tag = commit sha)
- Push image to registry
- Checkout frontend-chart repo
- Commit the new image tag to a feature branch in frontend-chart repo
- Open PR in frontend-chart repo (if no already opened)
- Wait until build succeeded for chart-frontend repo (feature branch)
- Merge to master

// chart-frontend repo | feature branch
* Trigger: open pr
- Deploy frontend chart
- Deploy all 3 other services. Install latest packaged charts.
- Run e2e tests
- Merge to master

// frontend repo | master branch
* Trigger: commit
- retag image to latest
- push image
- Trigger chart-frontend repo

// chart-frontend repo | master branch
* Trigger: build triggered by frontend repo master branch
- determine new chartversion
- helm package with new chartversion
- Add git tag
- push to chartmuseum
- checkout umbrella chart repo
- commit change, to use new chart version for frontend-chart on,  to feature branch.
- Open PR on umbrella repo to merge feature branch to master

// umbrella-chart repo | feature branch
* Trigger: open PR
- Deploy the chart
- Run e2e tests
- Merge to master

// umbrella-chart repo | master branch
* Trigger: merged pr/commit
- Determine new chart version
- package chart with new chart version
- publish chart
- Add git tag
- trigger deployment to acc

// env repo | acc branch
* Trigger: build triggered by umbrella-chart with parameters
- deploy newest dyet chart
- import data from production
- run e2e tests
- merge to production

// env repo | production branch
* Trigger: merged pr/commit
- deploy newest dyet chart
- run e2e tests
- (on failure: rollback)
```

Comment: For the CI part, each service should be able to be built and tested independently.  For deployment, each component can have its own Helm chart, and a typical Kubernetes style is to just crash and restart if a dependency isn't available (yet).  I'd avoid a Helm umbrella chart for a couple of reasons that don't fit in this comment.  This is an incredibly open-ended question, though; is there a specific part of the build sequence you're having trouble with?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for you answer. Oke so every component should stand on its own (independent services), but then where in the process do you include integration tests?

Comment: @DavidMaze And could you elaborate a bit on why you discourage the use of umbrella charts? My plan is to release the application as a whole (Helm chart), including frontend, backend, etc. So that the end-user can deploy it easily.

Comment: There's two practical problems I've run into.  Let's say that you have _two_ backends.  Each has its own database storage, but uses the same database technology; in a Helm umbrella chart, the top-level release would only install one database.  If you further take a major-version update to the database chart of one backend but not the other, then the dependency tree can't be resolved.